# how to split the string using delimiter in SQL SELECT QUERY in sybase? without using function or procedure in SYBASE

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, sybase

data: "500020,rcord.dat,CIND,A1WSQ,NID,N1265,NID,PP23"

I want extract the data between the two NID.
And also to extract the data after 5 th comma(,)

I want only the sql SELECT query not procedure or function

thanks for you help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: Even though the duplicate question is for SQL Server, it's likely the same or very close in Sybase ASE.  Also, it's helpful to know what you have already tried, and the actual software/version you are running, as Sybase was a company that produced a number of different database products.

Comment: I have tried the below quert,

Comment: select substr(substr(col1,instr(col1,',',1,5)+1),1,instr(substr(col1,instr(col1,',',1,5)+1),',')-1) from tab1;

Comment: sybase version: sybase ase 11.9.2

Comment: please help me on this issue